# synchronizing type of two python variables

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to change the type of one python variable to be of the type of a second variable. Currently I'm doing this with the below function (which works fine).

So if original_var is an int and new_var is a string:

```
def sync_type(original_var, new_var):
    if type(original_var) == type(new_var):
        return new_var
    if type(original_var) == int:
        return int(new_var)
    if type(original_var) == float:
        return float(new_var)
    if type(original_var) == bytes:
        return new_var.to_bytes(2, "big")

new_var = sync_type(original_var, new_var)
```

`type(new_var)` becomes a string

It just feels like there should be a smarter way to do this. Something like:

```
new_var = new_var.astype(original_var)
```

Comment: The fact that you're writing this function suggests that a design mistake has already been made somewhere. The function means too many drastically different things depending on what the arguments are.

Comment: There are very few realistic uses for such a function. It's the kind of thing a new programmer would write if they're struggling with when to use what types and they just want to make all the TypeErrors go away somehow.